# What taxes were legally required to be paid in silver in Qing China?

Tags: china, taxes, qing-dynasty, silver

### Background

It is often argued that the following mechanism heavily contributed to the commencement of the opium trade between the Qing and British Empires (you are welcome to correct my understanding):

- Certain Qing taxes had to be paid in silver
- Foreign trade transactions in the Qing Empire were only allowed in silver
- Britain had a significant trade deficit with regard to Qing
- This severely depleted European silver reserves
- Britain sought to reverse that by introducing a new trade, the opium trade.

It has proven very difficult for me to find citable evidence for parts of the above. For the earlier Ming Dynasty I found some more concrete claims [here](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-hccc-worldcivilization/chapter/the-economy-under-the-ming-dynasty/), though it’s unclear upon what they are based:

> Silver was required to pay provincial taxes in 1465, the salt tax in 1475, and corvée exemptions in 1485.

[This](http://projects.mcah.columbia.edu/nanxuntu/html/economy/) website about Qing economy claims that:

> During the Qing period, all Chinese people had to pay part of their taxes to the government in money (usually copper coins or silver) as opposed to goods-in-kind

making it sound like there was no obligation to use silver! Perhaps it was more a consequence of the copper coin’s low value, that is a practical consideration?

**Edit**

It appears that I have found such a law for the earlier Ming Dynasty. The Wikipedia [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_whip_law) on the *Single Whip Law* states:

> The unit of tax collection was changed from rice to silver, which led to an increase in the import of silver into China from Japan and Spanish-controlled America.

### Question

**Around 1839, which types of taxes were required by Qing law to be paid in silver?**

Did this apply to everyone, including peasants in remote regions?
I will welcome answers pointing to scientific articles, but particularly  hope for references to a Chinese source from the period or translation thereof.

Comment: Trade deficit, with the only product that China wanted was silver. Nowt to do with taxes per se.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It is my understanding that the most usable currency was copper, but the qing taxes were due in silver. This meant a huge tax increase for poorer farmers, which in turn led farmers to abandon their land, further lowering state revenue. It's all about silver.

Comment: I wonder how to provide a concise answer to the points you've raised. I think it's better if you read the book, ["***Central Government Silver Treasury: Revenue, Expenditure and Inventory Statistics, ca. 1667-1899***" (Brill, 2016)](https://brill.com/view/title/32003). I believe Chapter 3, *Silver Treasury Revenues during the Qing Dynasty* may be what you're after ([here](https://brill.com/view/book/9789004307339/B9789004307339_005.xml?crawler=true)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even under the early Qing when silver was relatively abundant, taxes weren't necessarily paid by households with physical silver, only assessed / denominated *in terms of* silver. As [one article](http://www.econhistdbm.com/uploads/8/1/9/7/81977286/state_capacity_and_great_divergence_the_case_of_qing_china_1644_1911.pdf) (which cites [a book by Man-hong Lin](https://books.google.com/books/about/China_Upside_Down.html?id=-p-eAAAAIAAJ)) states:

> Qing fiscal revenue... was **levied in silver [tael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tael) but collected** from
>   small holders who typically paid **in copper** cash.

This important modification does not fundamentally contradict the general argument outlined above. Quoting [another article](http://www.lse.ac.uk/Economic-History/Assets/Documents/Research/GEHN/GEHNWP06HZ.pdf):

> As the massive inflow of silver, which had sustained China's
>   balance-of-trade surplus through the eighteenth century, suddenly
>   became a trickle by 1820, the Chinese economy went into reverse. 
>   Prices dropped, commercial enterprises faltered, and market demand
>   slackened. The rising value of silver (because of its scarcity) also
>   increased the hardship of taxation, because **peasants were compelled to
>   relinquish more of their crops in order to meet their tax requisitions
>   that were still assessed in silver**. The depreciating copper-silver
>   exchange rate also exacerbated peasant purchasing power.

Comment: Oh, yes! This is an important realisation! Even without physically paying in silver, scarcity of the „measure“ can have a huge impact. Why did it become a trickle?

Comment: @Ludi 1820s was when opium imports started to take off. I'm guessing that was the main reason.